# Can anyone help me to understand the ArrayList<ArrayDeque<ByteBuffer>> type?

Tags: java

I found the type [here](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/io/kickflip/sdk/av/FFmpegMuxer.java):

```
ArrayList<ArrayDeque<ByteBuffer>> mMuxerInputQueue;
```

I can't understand it well.

Why are defined as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more info we should know where you found this declaration and why you need to use it... but, resuming..

**You have a list that contains in each position a collection of bytes**

Lets explain better:

- You have an `ArrayList` until here all ok. Right?
- This `ArrayList` contains, **in each position** a collection called  [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html):

  > Resizable-array implementation of the Deque interface. Array deques have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support usage. They are not thread-safe; in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads. Null elements are prohibited. This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.
- And this [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) contains, in each position a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), that is an extension of [`Buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html), **it's a container of `Byte`s**:

  > **Buffer:** A container for data of a specific primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

`mMuxerInputQueue` type is `ArrayList` which takes in `ArrayDeque` as it's elements. `ArrayDeque` takes `ByteBuffer` as it's elements

```
ArrayList<ArrayDeque<ByteBuffer>> mMuxerInputQueue = new ArrayList<>();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
ArrayDeque deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.add(buffer);
mMuxerInputQueue.add(dequeu)
```